# Is there a way in Firebase Cloud Firestore to check if a Path is in an Array<Reference> of a document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to add security rules to a new Firestore project I'm working on. I have a collection named `users` that has all my user data in it in this format in my Firestore database:

```
var users = {
    "userId": {
        friend_requests: [],
        friends: [
            /users/friendId1,
            /users/friendId2
        ],
        name: "User One",
        username: "user1"
    },
    "friendId1": {
        friend_requests: [],
        friends: [
            /users/userId
        ],
        name: "User Two",
        username: "user2"
    },
    "friendId2": {
        friend_requests: [],
        friends: [
            /users/userId
        ],
        name: "User Three",
        username: "user3"
    },
    "lonelyUser": {
        friend_requests: [],
        friends: [],
        name: "Lonely User",
        username: "lonely_user"
    }
}
```

My Firestore rules are this, verbatim:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if false;
        }

        match /users/{userId} {
            allow read: if isOwner(userId) || isFriendOf(userId);
        }
    }

    function isOwner(userId) {
        return userId == currentUser().uid;
    }

    function isFriendOf(userId) {
        return getUserPath(userId) in getUserData().friends;
    }

    function currentUser() {
        return request.auth;
    }

    function getUserData() {
        return get(getUserPath(currentUser().uid)).data;
    }

    function getUserPath(userId) {
        return /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId);
    }
}
```

The keys in the map I outlined above are Firebase user ids in my actual db, so when logged in as user "userId" I'd expect to be able to read the user document for both "friendId1" and "friendId2" users.

The problem I'm having is that `isFriendOf` is returning false. I've tried a few variants of wrapping the comparison data in a `get` call and passing in other values like  `id` and `data` off the resource it returns.

I've also tried wrapping the `getUserPath` call in `isFriendOf` in a `get` and then using the `__name__` property of the document as the comparison value as well. No luck there either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Including a screenshot of the actual documents for clarification.

[Screenshot of Firebase Documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EAiO.png)

Edit 2: I've made a clean firebase project with only the information in these new screenshots in it. I'm including screenshots of Firebase Authentication page, both user entries in the database, as well as a failed simulator run as one user trying to get the document of the other user.

[Authentication Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwxf3.jpg)

[user1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHfXH.jpg)

[user2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYXBC.jpg)

[Simulated Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqns8.jpg)

Comment: These rules for for me in the console simulator.  Please edit the question to show the actual data you're working with, perhaps a screenshot of the documents in the console.  In particular, verify the types of the friends list elements by hovering the mouse over their values.

Comment: I've edited my post to include a screenshot, those entries in friends are references if I open them to edit them.

Comment: Well, like I said, the rules work for me in the console simulator.  Do you have anything additional to say about how exactly you're performing your document read that should be allowed but is getting rejected?

Comment: Hey, I updated my post to include more detailed screenshots of the exact setup I have in firebase. Would you mind sharing the data you used that the rules worked with? Maybe I've just structured something wrong...

Comment: I'm doing the same thing as you, except my user IDs are just 1, 2, 3, and the document only contains a friends field array.

Comment: So, I just tried it using simple numbers for the ids, and that changed nothing for me. Thanks for trying to help, I appreciate it.